# Unable to Logout in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am logged in my android studio with google account, every time I click on the picture icon it generates some error to be submitted and nothing else,  I want to logout my account .
I am on linux , I tried deleting `~/.config/Google/` folder as well but that didn't work.

[icon image](https://imgur.com/a/nMRHYyY)

[error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6wW1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it and got this reply.

> This is fixed in Studio Hedgehog, which should make it to stable pretty soon.
> In the mean time you can work around this by deleting $HOME/.java/.userPrefs/com/google/gct/login/prefs.xml

So yeah, Just delete the `$HOME/.java/.userPrefs/com/google/gct/login/prefs.xml` file and you're good.